# Newly downloaded 1.6.1 Orchard CMS wont build

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I just downloaded the 1.6.1 source for Orchard CMS.

I loaded the solution file into Visual Studio 2012 Express - and get 722 Errors, including:

```
Error   919 The type or namespace name 'WhenAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Orchard\Orchard.Profile\Tests\HttpClient.cs  29  10  Orchard.Profile
```

Any idea what the problem is here?

I'm new to Orchard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the 'src' folder to wwwroot - and tried building.

You have to copy the entire 'Orchard.Source' folder - then load the solution in src within that folder - keeping all the files in place.

Answer (score 0):

When you downloaded Orchard source code, i saw many .bat file: build.cmd, ClickToBuild.cmd... => For prepare before open the solution,